# VScode customize integrated terminal to not show all paths in the output

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04

VScode version 1.52.1
Linux Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I would like to customize the output of the integrated terminal, see picture attached, virtual environment output, and other unnecessary path information in the output.

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: these paths are added by the extension to make sure it always work no matter what your current directory is

Comment: So in short, it is not possible to customize that to make the output look cleaner and less distracting?

Answer (score 0):

In VScode, go into your settings.json file (ctrl+shift+P to search for it) and scroll down to find the Terminal section. Add the code below just to get you started...

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "terminal.background": "#111111",
    "terminal.foreground": "#05ff2e",
  ...
  }
```

Comment: Color Customizations? I will check but just by reading the settings, I don't see how colors will help to tell the integrated terminal to stop presenting the additional path information.